# PostgreSQL streaming replication network connection

Tags: postgresql, replication, firewall, database-replication

We want to set up the streaming replication in a secure environment. The master is on the inside, and slave is on the outside. There is a network restriction that the firewall allows only outbound connections : master -> slave.

In a normal setup the slave connects to the master. Is there a way to reverse this?

The simple answer that I have thought of is to use the SSH tunnel from the inside to the outside (the tunnel gets created in the outbound direction), and then the slave can connect to the master through this tunnel.

Is there some other solution more native to the PostgreSQL server?

Comment: Do you really need streaming? You can easily push completed WAL segments in the other direction via [`archive_command`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-ARCHIVE-COMMAND), and you can minimise the replication lag via `archive_timeout`, if you can tolerate the WAL bloat.

Comment: I am really looking for a streaming solution. Will also think about you proposed solution, bu I'd like to find a solution for the streaming replication.